# Django Unknown column 'pm' in 'weather_weather'

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project, connecting to database use mariadb

And I used pm Field first .

However, I changed pm Field into rainfall in models.py.

```
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| time        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| temperature | decimal(3,1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| humidity    | decimal(3,1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| uv          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| light       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rainfall    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

This is my 4th [migrations file](http://codepad.org/GzgOK3kO)

This is my 3th [migration file](http://codepad.org/DJAoqQHI)

When I executed `python manage.py makemigrations`

It said no change detected

But when I executed `python manage.py migrate`

Then it said  Unknown column 'pm' in 'weather_weather'

Why?

Comment: "Why?" what? Why you changed the pm field into rainfall? I don't think anyone would know except you. What precisely is your question?

Comment: Please post full traceback.

Comment: Need to see your models, and the migrations files you linked contains error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that table is from your database, then it looks as if you have already renamed the column.

In that case, you won't be able to run the migration to rename `pm` to `weather`, because the `pm` column no longer exists.

You can tell Django to mark the migration as applied with the [`--fake`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake) option.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake weather 0004
```